# Blue screen - Windows 10 with Bootcamp on MacBook Pro 2015

Tags: windows, bootcamp

I have a MacBook Pro mid-2015 with High Sierra 10.13.
I installed Windows 10 (last version downloaded last week). This was done manually, as the Bootcamp software that comes with macOS creates a partition that Windows wouldn't install on.
Installation was completed without any problems.
Now I got several blue screens, sometimes at the start, sometimes few minutes later, sometimes shutting down Windows 10.

The blue screen says: kernel_security_check failure

Have you got the same problems? Could you help me to resolve this issue?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The Boot Camp Assistant should have work in your case. I would suggest you did something wrong. As for your manual installation, you would have to include more details. Can you produce a listing of the root folder of the Windows installer drive? How did you acquire the Windows Support Software? At what step in the installation did you first encounter the problem? I can state that for some unknown reason, the Boot Camp Assistant always omits the Microsoft Reserved partition.

Comment: Hi David, I didn’t use bootcamp standard installation because there was a problem with OSXRESERVED partition. 8GB is not enough space for windows 10 iso + windows support software, so Boot camp gave me this error ” The Windows support software could not be saved to the selected drive. There is not enough space available on the disk.”

Comment: So i did the installation manually, creating OSXRESERVED partition a little bit bigger (and putting in it win 10 iso + windows support software), following this video guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OWqpAd6MEbU&list=WL&index=12 
I used Bootcamp just to download windows support software. 

Doing it I didn’t get any error, installation was completed without any issues. I got the first blue screen after all, when I tried to download a file with the browser with win 10. 

In the first post I attached the list of root folder of the windows installer.

Comment: Probably it was better if I had installed an older ISO windows version (maybe  1803)  that does not cause the problem with Boot Camp Assistant, and then I simply ran Windows Update after the installation completed.  But now i can't go back because i can't delete BootCamp partition (Bootcamp Assistant won't work and in disk utility the minus option is not enabled to remove the partition)

Comment: I do not see the Windows Support Software in the image you posted.

Comment: sry, added right now

Comment: You can not use the Boot Camp Assistant to remove the Windows partition because you have a Microsoft Reserved partition. The command `diskutil erasevolume free none disk0s3` can be use to remove the Microsoft Reserved partition.

Comment: I assume you have installed all the updates available from Microsoft including any optional hardware drivers. Have you installed all the updates available from Apple? In other words, have you run the Apple Software Update application that was added when you installed Boot Camp into Windows.

Comment: I installed all the updates from Apple using Apple Software update. I also installed almost everything with windows updated (including some drivers), except and update about windows 21h2 because when I restart to update, it gets to 30%, then the laptop restarts, then it runs an automatic repair and removes the update files, once the laptops is on, I find this error code in the settings (windows update): 0x800f0845.

Comment: Maybe can I download new drivers from https://www.bootcampdrivers.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

The procedure you used to manually install the current Windows 10 (21H2) appears to be correct. You state to be having problems installing Windows updates. While I assume your question is asking what you are do wrong, you should consider the following.

From [everyman.com](https://everymac.com/systems/by_year/macs-released-in-2015.html), below is a list of all 2015 Mac models. Note that only the Mid-2015 MacBook Pro models are using [4th generation Intel Core i7 processors](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/series/75023/4th-generation-intel-core-i7-processors.html).

[image]

[Apple](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201468) states all 2015 Macs are Windows 10 compatible. However, [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/minimum/supported/windows-10-21h2-supported-intel-processors) lists all processors used in 2015 Macs as Windows 10 (21H2) compatible, **except for the processors used in the Mid-2015 MacBook Pro models**. In fact, ***none*** processors used in the Mid-2015 MacBook Pro models are list by [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/minimum/windows-processor-requirements#windows-client-edition-processors) as compatible with Windows 7, Windows 8.1 and all releases of Windows 10.

So you may have to try different releases of Windows 10 and/or restrict a Windows installation from installing updates that may be causing your problem. Evidently, [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/en/) can be used to download older releases of Windows 10.

### Using Rufus to Download an Older Release of Windows 10

1. From Windows, download the portable version of [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/en/). I use a VirtualBox Windows 10 virtual machine on a macOS host.
2. Open Rufus. (In my case, this was `rufus-3.18p.exe`.) If there is no down arrow next to the `SELECT` button as shown below, then click on the "Show application setting" button and change "Check for updates" to `Daily (Default)`.

   [image]

   Next, close and reopen Rufus. There should now be a down arrow next to the `SELECT` button, as shown below.

   [image]
3. Click on the down arrow and select `DOWNLOAD`. The result is shown below.

   [image]
4. Click on the `DOWNLOAD` button and wait for the popup shown below.

   [image]
5. Select the Version, Release, Edition, Language, and Architecture, as shown in the example below.

   [image]
6. Click on the Download button, then select where to save the download. The download should proceed, as shown below.

   [image]

Comment: ok thanks, I'll try to re-install an older ISO.